# Persist Spark df in S3 with random hash in file name prefix

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

[AWS best practices](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/request-rate-perf-considerations.html) for optimizing performance in Amazon S3 is using a random hashed prefix of three or four characters before or as a part of the file name.

I want to persist a dataframe in Parquet or ORC format in S3 and I am currently using the `df.write()` method. I am looking for a way in spark to generate a random prefix for each *part* file that is written for each partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it gets complex when you have field values in the tree, e.g

`visits/year=2017/month=08/day=22/.....orc.snappy
visits/year=2016/month=08/day=22/.....orc.snappy`

if you are querying into a month or day, all your work is focusing on the same s3 shard.

you really want randomness above every year=, month= maybe day= so that things are spread out more

`visits/_34ac_year=2017/_aba1_month=08/_13df_day=22
visits/_76a3_year=2016/_bc00_month=08/_7f02_day=22`

You need to not only change the partitioning structure on save, but have it handled on load too, so that when you do a query over year=2017 month=08, those random chars are stripped.  The issue is not generating the randomness on saves: it's those queries.

Nothing I know does this in raw spark as of September 2017; maybe Qubole have got a story there.

To be honest, I would be surprised if you were really hitting the limits, because the way AWS reacts to it is sending 503 exceptions back. If you were using the S3a client you'd be seeing stack traces, as it doesn't do the backoff & retry on those (yet) [Update: 8-sept-2017: the limits are apparently being reached]

Comment: I did hit those limits. So, I am trying to save the parts using their best practices. But it is difficult to do this in Spark.

Comment: its not so much spark as the expectations of the entire toolchain about file layout, specifically Parquet and ORC. There's also the naming of partition output as part-0000, part-0001. In the netflix staging committer they add a UUID at the end of those part-0000 values, but that's to deal with update inconsistency more than lookup performance.

If you are hitting those limits, you are on EMR not s3a, correct?

Comment: Correct. Do you know any workaround to this problem?

Comment: Afraid I don't.  I can make s3a resilient to throttle failurs (amongst others), but moving towards randomised filenames is a lot harder as it would have to go in at the application level, and be standardised across multiple apps

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
import scala.util.Random

df.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .save(s"myFile_${Random.alphanumeric take 10 mkString("")}")
```

Comment: This does not prepend a different hash before each part that is being saved by Spark.